# Using gzip_types/ssi_types in NGINX with "wildcard" media types

Tags: nginx

We have an application, serving json with media type: `application/vnd.example.v1.0+json` and `application/vnd.example.v2.0+json` and so on.

If we want to use nginx's http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#ssi_types and http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_types. Do we have to append every possible version number or is there something like a wildcard?

Instead of:

```
gzip_types "application/vnd.example.v1.0+json" "application/vnd.example.v2.0+json" "application/vnd.example.v3.0+json"
```

is something like

```
gzip_types "application/vnd.example*+json"
```

possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to NGINX source code `src/http/ngx_http.c`:

```
if (value[i].len == 1 && value[i].data[0] == '*') {
```

No, you can't